# Simulated annealing, normalized temperature

Tags: python, algorithm, mathematical-optimization, simulated-annealing

I have a problem that I need to maximize the value X of the given function:

[image: math formula]

This is the python code for the formula: `2 ** (-2 *((((x-0.1) / 0.9)) ** 2)) * ((math.sin(5*math.pi*x)) ** 6)`.

I'm using the simulated annealing algorithm to this job, but I'm having a problem.

```
probability = pow(math.e, (actual_cost - best_cost) / temperature)
```

My "cost" (what I'm trying to optimize) is a very short number, most often between 0 and 0.1, but my temperature, in the other side, is like 100.

So, when I apply the probability function, my result is always something like 99%, which makes my algorithm accept negative values in all iterations, instead of decreasing this probability throughout the iterations.

How can I adapt the value of my temperature to change the probability through the iterations?

Comment: Why is your temperature fixed? Usually you pick it depending on your problem. If you are not bound to using your own algorithm, there is an implementation available: [scipy.optimize.basinhopping](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.basinhopping.html). The default value for `T` in that function is 1.0 .

Comment: It's a good option, i'll try to study this implementation to understand more about how i could set a good temperature for my problems! Tanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this can be found in the docs for [scipy.optimize.basinhopping](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.basinhopping.html):

> Choosing `T`: The parameter `T` is the “temperature” used in the
>   Metropolis criterion. Basinhopping steps are always accepted if
>   `func(xnew) < func(xold)`. Otherwise, they are accepted with
>   probability:
>
> `exp( -(func(xnew) - func(xold)) / T )`
>
> So, for best results, `T` should to be comparable to the typical
>   difference (in function values) between local minima. (The height of
>   “walls” between local minima is irrelevant.)
>
> If `T` is 0, the algorithm becomes Monotonic Basin-Hopping, in which all
>   steps that increase energy are rejected.